# shallowWrapper is empty, testing snapshot Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme, enzyme-to-snapshot

I don't know why i get empty `shallowWrapper` object when i run snapshot test, i am using **Jest** and **Enzyme**:

What i get in **App.test.js.snap** file:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, "goo.gl/fbAQLP"
exports[`renders App component 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;
```

my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0-next.98"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.4",
    "jest": "^26.4.2"
  }
}
```

**App.test.js** file

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';


it('renders App component', () => {
  expect(shallow(<App />)).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

**setupTests.js** file:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ 
    adapter: new Adapter()
 });
```

Why i get that empty `shallowWrapper` object, I suspected the version of jest after some search, but even downgrading didn't solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into similar problem and playing around with jest help me got through it. I suggest you can clear the jest cache and then update the snapshots using `jest --clearCache && jest -u` and then run your test.

Also for your snapshot, I'd recommend you to use `enzyme-to-json` serialiser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-to-json) and modify your test to:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

it('renders App component', () => {
  const app = shallow(<App />);
  expect(shallowToJson(app)).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

Comment: When i run the command ```jest --clearCache ``` i get that message
```'jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file```

Comment: That may probably due to jest not being present globally. You can instead put the clear cache command as an npm script and run that script so that node picks it from local node modules.

Answer (score 1):

The shallow( ) did returned the output. Shallow works as a wrapper instance with the rendered output. You could use shallow( ) method with debug( ) to see what prints out. If you want to see the rendered output，you could use shallow().html( ) inside the expect( ) method to test again.